# Copy sub-directory from 1 directory to another

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, terminal, server

I need to make a copy of the content of one directory to another.
I need to copy only 1 sub-folder. 
For example; if I have a folder called "**from**" and want to copy one of it's sub-folders (with all the stuff inside it) that's called "**21-01-2015**" to folder "**to**"

```
+ from
    - 21-01-2015 (**this name changes all the time**)
    - month (**this stays always the same**)
```

I'm currently using this command: `cp -a /path/from /path/to` but this command does a copy of folder "**from**" along with all the stuff within it...

so when you're inside folder "**to**" it becomes something like this:

```
+ to
    + from
        - 21-01-2015
        - month
```

instead of how I need it which is

```
+ to
    - 21-01-2015
```

how can I achieve something like this?
thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is cross-posted already: http://askubuntu.com/questions/576321/copy-sub-directory-from-1-directory-to-another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your directories will always have that format (at least as far as the number of digits are concerned):

```
for dir in `ls -1 /path/from | grep -e '^\d\{2\}-\d\{2\}-\d\{4\}'`; do
  cp -a /path/from/$dir /path/to
done
```

This should be tolerant even of multiple directories in `/path/from` that match the pattern (2 digits-2 digits-4 digits).  So even if your cronjob misses a day, as long as it gets to run before the folder gets pruned from `/path/from` you should still catch up.

Comment: yep, but "21-01-2015" changes everyday and I want to run a cronjob. So I need to copy everything from inside folder "from" except the folder "month"

Comment: @user4480106 Okay, thanks for the clarification.  Edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put this together!! I highly appreciate!!